# angularJS display +1 month date

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

**here is code:**

```
date:  new Date(2015,12,8)
```

**and html:**

```
<span>{{task.date | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</span>
```

but angularJS displays this date like
**01/08/2016** 
and I don't know why it's display +1 month
what I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript Date object the months are indexed starting with zero - i.e. Januray == 0.

In other words, you may want to change your date creation as follows:

```
date:  new Date(2015,11,8)
```

please, notice that **11** stands for **December**

Answer (score 1):

Months are indexed from 0. So your january month is 0 and Feb is 1 and so on. The reason why it starts with zero and not one, may be because it helps with indexing into arrays.